# Troubles with git am when applied in a different repository

Tags: git, patch, git-commit, git-add, git-am

I have two Git repositories:

1. ```
   /api/pom.xml
   /jpa/pom.xml
   ```
2. ```
   /mailbox/api/pom.xml
   /mailbox/jpa/pom.xml
   /protocols/api/pom.xml
   ```

The second repository have a mailbox folder that has the exact same structure
that the first Git repository. Due to workflow changes, I now need to work on
the second repository, and need to transfer my working branches to the new
repository.

I created a patch in the first one (let say on file `api/pom.xml`)
and try to apply it in the second one, under the `/mailbox` path. So I have only
one problem: `git am` refuses to do the work, pretending that:

```
<file> does not exist in index
```

I tried directory option and `-p1` option. Note: `patch -p1` does the job, but I
have ~80 patch to apply in all my branches:

```
patch + git add + git commit
```

Is there any cheaper way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to consider `mailbox` in your second repo as being the first one, declared as  a **[submodule](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)**:

```
cd /path/to/second/repo
git submodule add -- /url/first/repo mailbox
```

That way, once you have done some changes in `mailbox` folder, you add and push (to the first repo from the mailbox submodule folder), then `cd ..` to the main parent repo, add and push (recording the **[gitlink](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)**, [special entry in the index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354410/6309)).

No more patch needed.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! I thought to it. But code comes from SVN => git replication and I need to do that in an existing repository... The funny part is that the first repository is a submodule :-p

Comment: @Benwa that should prevent you to add that git repo as a submodule, while doing from that git repo some git svn command.